# MAPIInitialize( ) fails after April 24, 2020 update of Office 365

Tags: office365, mapi

Starting on April 22, 2020 this code snippet started failing:

```
 HRESULT hRes;
 MAPIINIT_0 MAPIINIT= { 0, MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS};
 hRes = MAPIInitialize(&MAPIINIT);   <---  Program halts here.
```

This code has been running without a problem since at least the year 2000 (20 years).

This failed on at least one computer after an Office 365 Update. However, this problem is associated with several different Outlook versions:

Office 365 Version 2005 - 16.0.12823.20000 64bit - Windows Insider.

Office 365 Version 2003 - 12624.20520 (Click to Run) - Current Release.

So far - only on Windows 10.

Has anyone found a way to run MAPIInitialize( )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the latest Insider Slow (Monthly) update broke `MAPIInitialize`.

Microsoft is aware of the problem, but there is no fix yet.
The only workarounds are either installing the Insider Fast build (https://www.msoutlook.info/question/office-365-for-business-office-insider-fast-builds) or downgrading to one of the previous versions  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic

You can also try to modify the system PATH:
https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/issues/367

Loading

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\Mso20win32client.dll
```

and

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OutlookServicing.dll
```

prior to calling MAPIInitialize() gets rid of the crash.

Comment: Is there somewhere an official statement from Microsoft that this is a bug and they are aware of it? Something i can point my user to while they are pointing at me because my software looks broke?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I agree - is there anything from Microsoft that we can pass to our customers?

Comment: >  Yes, the latest Insider Slow (Monthly) update broke MAPIInitialize.

We have found this problem in Insider Fast, and also monthly channel when tyou press "Check for Updates".

Comment: I am not aware of anything official - it will take longer to publish a KB article than to actually fix the problem and push out the update (probably withing a week or so).

Comment: Today's version from the monthly targeted channel seems to be fixed.

Comment: It seems like they actually pulled 16.0.12730.20206 out and pushed 16.0.12730.20144

Answer (score 1):

For us, the System Path modification worked well. The exact path is different for different versions including 32/64 bit. We built a small executable to handle this in an end-user-friendly way:

https://www.companionlink.com/files/special/Fix365MAPI.exe

```
To add path:  fix365mapi
To remove path:  fix365mapi /u
Reboot the PC to ensure the path is used.
```

We have a large installed base.  We have validated the problem with customers who have  Insider Slow, Insider Fast, Insider Fast (April 27 update), and Monthly customers.  However, clearly only a fraction of our installed base are seeing this problem. So there must be a second factor, maybe (Click-to-run) or the April Windows 10 update in addition to the Office 365 update.

In our testing adding the path fixed the issue so it looks like a simple dependency problem.