# Failed to create object of Redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

Earlier the same code was running but when I ran the code yesterday started getting error 
at below line of code
Dim rdoSessionToCheck As RDOSession = New RDOSession()

Error:
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8000ffff Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).

environment:
windows 10
outlook for microsoft 365

Comment: please post some code that fires this error, it will help get answers

Comment: I have resolved the issue by running online repair for office for Office365. This resolved the issue. So if anyone face such issue can try online repair process to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the bitness of Microsoft Office corresponds to the Redemption library. However, there was an issue with recent Office builds in the MAPI subsystem which is described on the [MAPIInitialize( ) fails after April 24, 2020 update of Office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469343/mapiinitialize-fails-after-april-24-2020-update-of-office-365) post.

Make sure that you have the latest Office build installed. The recent issue with `MAPIInitialize` is fixed in Outlook Insider channel Version 2006 (Build 12829.20000) and in Monthly channel Version 2004 (Build 12730.20250).

Answer (score 0):

The latest Insider Slow (Monthly) build of Outlook (versions 16.0.12730.20206 and 16.0.12624.20520) breaks `MAPIInitialize` Extended MAPI function (it just crashes with an access violation).

The problem is common to all application that use MAPI, not just Redemption. Microsoft is aware of the problem; a fix should probably be available in a week or so.
The only workarounds are installing the Insider Fast build (https://www.msoutlook.info/question/office-365-for-business-office-insider-fast-builds) or downgrading to one of the previous versions  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic 
You can also try to update the system PATH variable: https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/issues/367

There is also a special build of Redemption that works around this problem - please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com if you need the updated version.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have resolved the issue by running online repair for office for Office365. This resolved the issue. So if anyone face such issue can try online repair process to resolve the issue.